# Please help install an Ubuntu desktop

Tags: unity, gnome

I have installed Ubuntu 12.04 base system on my IBM Thinkpad labtop. Then I installed the gnome-shell using apt-get, but it does not work: I have the error message "cannot open X windows manager". I also tried to install Unity (also using apt-get) but it does not work, showing these : "unity-panel-service: no process found" and "compiz(core) - Fatal: Couldn't open display :0"

What would you advise in order to properly install a simple Ubuntu desktop (which one)?

Thanks for your concern

Comment: Reads like you did not do anything yet with that system? If not, just re-install using the live dvd with the desktop you want. I would advice downloading 14.04 though. Messing with more than 1 desktop environments can cause problems.

Answer (score 1):

A solution for this might be, to install "tasksel"

> sudo apt-get install tasksel

starting it as root

> sudo tasksel

and then choosing your desktop enviroment from there.