# How can I move from Xubuntu 16.04 to Ubuntu 18.04?

Tags: 16.04, upgrade, do-release-upgrade, 18.04

Ubuntu 18.04 final beta came out a few days back. Ubuntu 18.04 will be released soon and I have recently upgraded RAM on my computer. I previously had less RAM so I started using Xubuntu, but now I want to move back to Ubuntu (although it's no longer the same, with GNOME desktop and all).

What would be the best way to do it? I don't want to lose data and would like to keep the applications I have installed on my Xubuntu 16.04 system. So in summary: I want to know if there's a way to move from Xubuntu 16.04 to Ubuntu 18.04 (with the GNOME desktop, not Xubuntu 18.04) and if yes, how reliable it is. Or would I have to just clean install?

Comment: [Ubuntu Development version / How to participate](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1018033/ubuntu-development-version-how-to-participate)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I upgrade from 14.04 LTS to 16.04.1 LTS?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/801488/how-do-i-upgrade-from-14-04-lts-to-16-04-1-lts) and [Please help install an Ubuntu desktop](https://askubuntu.com/questions/529803/please-help-install-an-ubuntu-desktop) and [In “Tasksel” how do I select a package?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/988900/in-tasksel-how-do-i-select-a-package)

Comment: The last time I looked Ubuntu 18.04 offers `Unity 7.5` as a Desktop in addition to `Gnome`. That said I think questions about `18.04` should only be asked ***after*** it's release date. In any case you don't want to be the first person upgrading Xubuntu 16.04 to Ubuntu 18.04.

Comment: @karel I updated the question to be more precise about what i wanted to ask.

Comment: Upgrading from Xubuntu 16.04 to Ubuntu 18.04 is reliable. Distribution upgrades have gotten more reliable in recent years. Then install Ubuntu desktop with the command `sudo apt-get install --install-suggests ubuntu-desktop` .

Comment: Thanks @karel .Would there be any issues because Gnome desktop needing GDM. Also will there be duplicated applications(eg. xfce and gnome file managers are different)?

Comment: I already went through that with gdm with no problems, it was all handled in the upgrade automatically. Multiple desktop environments and multiple desktop applications are also kept separate from each other automatically, and you can only login to one desktop environment at a time.

Answer (score 0):

```
sudo apt update && sudo apt dist-upgrade && sudo apt autoremove
sudo apt-get install update-manager-core
```

Then open the update-manager configuration file and make sure the Prompt line is set to lts

```
sudo nano /etc/update-manager/release-upgrades
```

Prompt=lts
then do the upgrade

```
  $ sudo do-release-upgrade
```

Comment: I wish to move from Xubuntu 16.04 to Ubuntu 18.04 once it releases. I wanted to know if there's a way.